# What is the best way of deploying my java app to AWS BeanStalk for small app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, jar, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am developing a modular monolith web application Spring Boot + Postgresql database using Elastic Beanstalk - EC2 + RDS. I am looking for a preferable way to deploy my app to AWS. Should I just deploy jar/war using file uploader. Is that a good practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends. If this is something that you have to do often, then maybe you could consider setting up the proper [CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/welcome.html) with Elastic Beanstaslk target.